# how to detect that am in the first or the last page when paginating in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

am working on a pagination using Firebase and so far i have a button to go forward and other one to get back and they are working fine ,but i have problem detecting either if am in the first page or the last page so i can disable the pagination buttons,so am wondering how that work and should i change the way i paginate data?

```
export const getNextItems = (last_Visible) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase }) => {
    const firestore = getFirebase().firestore();
    // const items = [];
    const dbRef = firestore
      .collection('items')
      .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
      .startAfter(last_Visible)
      .limit(2);

   const usersRef = firestore.collection('users');
    let temps = [];

    const { data: items, firstVisible, lastVisible } = await dbRef.get().then(getAllDocs);
   

    for (const item of items) {
      const { data: user } = await usersRef.doc(item.owner).get().then(getDoc);
      temps.push({ ...item, owner: user });
    }

    return { docs: temps, lastVisible, firstVisible };
  };
};


export const getPrevItems = (first_Visible) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase }) => {
    const firestore = getFirebase().firestore();
    // const items = [];
    const dbRef = firestore
      .collection('items')
      .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
      .endBefore(first_Visible)
      .limitToLast(2);
    const usersRef = firestore.collection('users');
    let temps = [];

    const { data: items, lastVisible, firstVisible } = await dbRef.get().then(getAllDocs);
    

    for (const item of items) {
      const { data: user } = await usersRef.doc(item.owner).get().then(getDoc);
      temps.push({ ...item, owner: user });
    }

    return { docs: temps, lastVisible, firstVisible };
  };
};
```

Comment: The only way to know if you're at the end is to ask for more documents than what you need, and see if you got less than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To detect whether there are more pages to load, you'll need to request an additional item. So since you seem to show 2 items per page, you should request 3 items - and display only two of them. If you get a third item, you know there's an additional page.